# javascript filter does not return array

Tags: javascript

I have this code.

```
console.log(
  "deleteHandler:",
  ...images.filter((image) => image._id !== imageId)
);
```

Docs say that `filter` returns an array. I expect the console output to return an array but it returns an object.

> deleteHandler: {user: {…}, _id: 'asdf', likes: Array(0), public: true, key: 'asdf.jpeg', …}

If I wrap it in an array I get an array in the console:

```
console.log(
  "deleteHandler:",
  [...images.filter((image) => image._id !== imageId)]
);
```

> deleteHandler: (2) [{…}, {…}]

But I do not understand why.

Comment: It does return an array. However, in your `console.log()` call, you're *spreading* that array into the argument list for `console.log()`.

Comment: To expand on the above, by using the spread operator, your code is effectively doing this: `console.log('deleteHandler:', images[0], images[1], images[2]... images[n])`. So quick fix: stop using the spread selector if you want to work with an array

Comment: Just stop maniacally spreading everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, yours didn't because the `...` [spreads the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
console.log(
  "deleteHandler:",
  images.filter((image) => image._id !== imageId)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without [...]: You're spreading individual elements as separate arguments, and it's displayed as objects.
With [...]: You're creating a new array and spreading elements into it, so it's correctly displayed as an array.
So, the behavior is due to how the spread operator interacts with console.log when spreading individual elements vs. spreading elements into a new array.